# Fixed CSS positioning of nav menu on floating navbar

Tags: css, menu, navigation, css-position

visualisation of problem: http://tinyurl.com/q83t89y

Is there a way to have the browse button to stay on the exact location that it is now?
For example if I resize my window or zoom in / out the browse button leaves its location.

Here is the css:

```
 <style>
  ul.Nav2 {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:auto;
}

ul.Nav2>li {
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   right: 25%;
   padding:0px;
   width:100px;
   height:20px;
   margin:10px;
   z-index: 9999;
   float: right;


}

ul.Nav2 li a {
  font-family:"Arial";
  font-size:15px;
  color:#FFF;
  display:block;
  width:auto;
  height:35px;
  line-height:20px;
/*removed
  text-align:center;
*/
  text-decoration:none;
  opacity:0.6;
  padding:0px 10px;
  ;
  ;
  ;
  -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

ul.Nav2 li a:hover {
  opacity:1;
}

ul.Nav2 ul {
  list-style:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999px;
  text-align:right;
  float:right
  /*added*/
  display:block;
  padding:0;
  min-width:9.3ex;
}

ul.Nav2 ul li {
  padding-top:1px;
  float:none;
}

ul.Nav2 ul a {
  white-space:nowrap;
}

ul.Nav2 li:hover ul {
  left:inherit;
}

ul.Nav2 li:hover a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul.Nav2 li:hover ul a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul.Nav2 li:hover ul li a:hover {
}
</style>
```

Comment: put it in a fiddle ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ul.Nav2>li` has been positioned to the right side of the browser. I think you should leave it alone and...

1. Create a fixed container `<div>` like radio bar. (Green box in the example below)
2. Set an invisible `<div>` in the center of container. (Red box)
3. Position the Browse menu to the centered box. (Blue box) Use `margin-left` to avoid overlapping the radio-bar.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Stocki/ZGzb6/